# Adding a new collection to an existing mongo database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an existing db with a bunch of collections in it. I need to add a new collection and was asked to create a script to add this collection in our production environment. Not sure how to approach this. When I search for this, I see docs pointing to insert() in mongodb, but that looks like a way to insert new documents in to an existing collection.

Is there a way to add a script to the load() function to be able to create a new collection inside my db?

Thanks!

Comment: when you do an insert with collection `xyz` specified, the collection `xyz` will create itself if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the mongo command line tool or use js files to do this.

By "script", I'm assuming make a js file.

In either the CLI or in a js file:

```
use video;
db.movies.insertOne({ "title": "Jaws", "year": 1975, "imdb": "tt0073195" });
db.movies.insertOne({ "title": "Mad Max 2: The Road Warrior", "year": 1981, "imdb": "tt0082694" })
db.movies.insertOne({ "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark", "year": 1981, "imdb": "tt0082971" })
```

Will insert those objects into a collection called video in a database called movies.

I suggest reading up on the mongo docs on how to use the CLI or pass js files to your instance because there are countless answers here on SO. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/
The mongo shell can be started with numerous options. See mongo shell page for details on all available options (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/) then run your commands.

Answer (score 1):

When you do an insert with collection `xyz` specified, the collection `xyz` will create itself if it does not exist yet.

You can do `createCollection` if you need specific options, but this is rare.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/